# Creation of commit object's Index in git?

Tags: git

Please guide me that the SHA that is created when the  commit object is created is either the SHA of only the contents of file or there are some other inputs too to the HASH function like author of commit,timestamp and date etc?

I have following confusion in my mind

```
commit object's index=SHA(Contents of file)?
             OR
commit object's index=SHA(Contents of file+author of commit+date of the day+time of the day)?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A commit in `git` never exists of pure file content, thus your first first assumption (SHA(contents of file)) is never true.  Actually, every *file* you check-in, gets stored as an object and *this* object's name is the file's SHA-sum.

But you don't even just check-in files, it's about a file *hierarchy*.  A file hierarchy is resembled by a *tree-object*, which contains all files in this (sub-)hierarchy (noted by their object name — SHA-sum), name and permissions of the files.  The object name of a tree-file is the SHA-sum over this listing.  This also works recursively, i.e. you can reference tree-objects from tree-objects (this is how subdirectories work).

Your actual *commit* consists of the SHA sums of (0 or more) parent-commits, the name of the tree-object resembling your repositorie's root-directory, commit date, commit author, commit message etc.  The commit name (the "revision number") is the SHA-sum over *this* listing.